# Magento : Update stock qty and status for different stores

Tags: magento, stock, inventory-management

Right now I am trying to update the stock status using the following query

```
$sql            = "UPDATE " . _getTableName('cataloginventory_stock_item') . " csi,
                   " . _getTableName('cataloginventory_stock_status') . " css
                   SET
                   csi.qty = ?,
                   csi.is_in_stock = ?,
                   css.qty = ?,
                   css.stock_status = ?
                   WHERE
                   csi.product_id = ?
                   AND css.website_id = ?
                   AND csi.product_id = css.product_id";
```

//update CA inventory

```
 $connection->query($sql, array($newQtyCA, $isInStockCA, $newQtyCA, $stockStatusCA, $productId,$website_id_CA));
```

//update USA inventory

```
$connection->query($sql, array($newQtyUS, $isInStockUS, $newQtyUS, $stockStatusUS, $productId,$website_id_US));
```

But this query doesn't update the stock for US site appropriately, can somebody let me know how exactly to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

By default this is not possible, stock is global not store(_view) based. You would have to add another product attribute for extra stocks.

Comment: Thanks for the info PvdL, even if i add extra attribute, how would the stocks add up, I would have to make changes manually in many places

Comment: Magento doesn't support multiple stock by default since a lot of rules would have to be configured, i.e. which stock first, spilt stock, different delivery costs/time. That sort of things. So... yeah you are "forced" to handle the stock yourself, I would consider an extra attribute for the second stock and overriding (not overwriting!) the stock model of a product to check your rules which stock/attribute value to load. Possibly even disabling stock checks and setting both stocks in separate attributes. If your second one is larger than the first Magento may/will bitch about invalid amounts